# What points are circumcenters of lattice points?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, rational-numbers, integer-lattices

What points in the plane can be written as the circumcenter of three lattice points?

The points that *cannot* be written this way have an interesting property: for any $r$, at most two lattice points are a distance $r$ away from them.

I know at least that all circumcenters are rational points, because they're the intersections of perpendicular bisectors which are rational lines.

I've also calculated a special case. The circumcenter of $(-1,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(a,b)$ is
$$\left(0,\frac{a^2+b^2-1}{2b}\right).$$

But I don't know how to tell if a given rational point can be written in that form, let alone as a circumcenter of any other triplet of lattice points.

I suppose it's possible that *all* rational points are the circumcenter of three lattice points, but I suspect that there are some that can't be written as the circumcenter of three lattice points, no matter how hard you try. But I don't know how I'd prove it, or how I'd catalogue them.

Comment: A related question could be to ask which rational points lie on the perpendicular bisector of two lattice points. (I suspect the answer is all of them - though, since the union of all of those bisectors has measure zero, we know there must be irrationals that don't lie on any)

Comment: Have you found an explicit expression for the circumcenter of points $(a_1, a_2), (b_1, b_2), (c_1, c_2)$ yet?

Comment: @TheBestMagician Not yet (because I fear the result will be horrible), but I'll try tomorrow after I've had some sleep

Comment: Cartesian coordinates of the circumcenter are $\left(\frac{X_O}{Z_O},\frac{Y_O}{Z_O}\right)$ where $\begin{pmatrix}X_O\\Y_O\\Z_O\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_A & x_B & x_C\\y_A & y_B & y_C\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a^2 (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)\\b^2 (c^2 + a^2 - b^2)\\c^2 (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)\end{pmatrix}$ and $a^2 = (x_B - x_C)^2 + (y_B - y_C)^2$ etc.

Comment: The above expressions for $(X_O:Y_O:Z_O)$ have a common factor (the oriented area of $ABC$). Cancelling that leaves cubic expressions for $X_O,Y_O$ and a quadratic (twice the oriented area of $ABC$) for $Z_O$.

Comment: That is, $\begin{pmatrix}X_O\\Y_O\\Z_O\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}(x_A^2+y_A^2)(y_B-y_C)+(x_B^2+y_B^2)(y_C-y_A)+(x_C^2+y_C^2)(y_A-y_B)\\(x_A^2+y_A^2)(x_C-x_B)+(x_B^2+y_B^2)(x_A-x_C)+(x_C^2+y_C^2)(x_B-x_A)\\2(x_B y_C-x_A y_C-x_C y_B+x_A y_B+x_C y_A-x_B y_A)\end{pmatrix}$